# Checking the length of a Command Line Argument in C#

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

What I am trying to do is ensure a Argument being passed from the command line is between a specific set of characters, however the code doesn't seem to be highlighting any issues when a value outside the acceptable range is used.

```
if (args[1].Length < 10 && args[1].Length > 40) // Test to see if the password is between 10 and 40 characters
{
Console.WriteLine("Please use a password between 10 and 40 characters");
Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

I was wondering if anyone might have any suggestions for why this is not working.
The arguments being passed are -e password file1.txt file2.txt

Thanks in Advance!

Alistair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the wrong logic, should be `||`

```
    if (args[1].Length < 10 || args[1].Length > 40) // Test to se
```

Comment: Doesn't that depend on whether the conditioned statement is the error or not? -- If the pwd length is below 10 or greater than 40, it is an error.

Comment: The conditioned statement is the error (I am catching anything outside of range before code is executed further)
Thanks for your Answer!

Answer (score 1):

The argument can't be both *smaller* in length than 10 **and** *longer* than 40. You should be choosing to meet either of these conditions (using the [Conditional OR Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6373h346.aspx)), but not strictly both:

```
if (args[1].Length < 10 || args[1].Length > 40)
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if (args[1].Length < 10 || args[1].Length > 40) // Test to see if the password is  between 10 and 40 characters
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please use a password between 10 and 40 characters");
   Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You gave wrong conditions:

It should be:

```
if (args[1].Length < 10 || args[1].Length > 40)
```